# how to side load something from another column of the same table when making an api call to a column?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, api, rest

Suppose I have a task table with two attributes one as Id and another as parent id along with other attributes.

Now I have two type of tasks :
One which is main task having parent I'd as null and another type of task which is a  sub-task having parent I'd as the another task in the same table to which it belongs to. I can create a task with both as task or as a sub-task( providing which task is its parent task )

When  I make a api call to fetch task I am side loading all the attributes and associated tables based on a
the filter.

The filter is also having an option to display parent task id and parent_task_name.

But the problem here is that since they are inside same table the api call is not side loading the same table itself and instead it's making an extra call to load the parent_task columns again.

I know we could have created two tables one as tasks and other as sub task in the very beginning but now that's not feasible.

So how I can avoid the extra api call just for getting parent_task_name and side load the parent task id and its name in same api call.

Comment: Could you please provide code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not shared your code so not sure how you are trying to do that but one way which I can think of is by using joins:

```
records = ChildModel.joins('INNER JOIN task_table AS parent ON task_table.parent_id = parent.id').select('task_table.*, parent.name AS parent_task_name').where(id: array_of_ids)
```

Here the `task_table` would be the name of your table.

So here we are joining the table with itself using an alias and getting the parent task attributes from it. To fetch the parent task name:

```
records.last.parent_task_name
```

This way you would get the records in a single query.